# Generate Paypal Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

Based on the title suggestions that come up I am beating a dead horse with an old stick, but have been stuck for a couple days now:

**The Situation:**  Present my users with a paypal button that passes an aggregate total of their shopping cart + tax to paypal so that they can pay with a credit card after checking out with my custom shopping cart.

**The issue:**  Paypal takes a post form with parameters for value and item_number and account number.  How do I create the "Form" so I can set the values of the form before the post?

First I started here: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside#methodone

Pretty basic:  Its a form that uses post to submit data to paypal.  First issue however is that the data is static in the form.  I can't programmatically change the values to that each user is presented with a customized form with their respective total and shopping cart id.

**My proposed solution:**
I created a class that gathers the required information to perform the post, then submits the post request with a `WebClient` object:

```
public class PAYPAL
{
    public string business { get; set; } //account email
    public string item_name { get; set; } //cartname
    public string currency_code { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
    public string URI { get; set; }
    public HttpResponse response { get; set; }
    public string responseBody { set; get; }
    public string ipnUrl { set; get; } //Instant Payment Notification (callback)

    public PAYPAL()
    {
        //Default Values
        currency_code = "USD";
        URI = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        ipnUrl = URI;
    }

    public void submit()
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
            nvc.Add("cmd", "_xclick");
            nvc.Add("business", business);
            nvc.Add("item_name", item_name); //cartname
            nvc.Add("currency_code", currency_code);
            nvc.Add("amount", amount.ToString());
            byte[] r = wc.UploadValues(URI, nvc);
            responseBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(r);
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to create the post request for paypal dynamically which solves my issue in theory, but of course as you probably have already guessed, this is submitted server side and so the user isn't redirected to paypals site as they would be if they had clicked on one of the normal buttons from the above mentioned paypal page.  My page just postbacks, and if I look at the response from the `WebClient` I am getting an error from paypal indicating that cookies are not enabled.... Probably due to the fact that its not really a browser accessing the page.

After some other research I have discovered that this is apparently a normal problem for ASP.NET developers.  The one solution I found cited that it was a great solution, but for whatever reason I was unable to successfully implement it:  http://jerschneid.blogspot.com/2007/03/hide-form-tag-but-leave-content.html

TL;DR
Is their a way to dynamcically create the paypal form?  Pr force the server generated WebClient to get transferred to the clients browser so that they can complete the transaction like they would if it was the static paypal form button from the first link?

Sorry again for the apparent redundancy of this question.

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:**

I changed my PAYAPL class to return a formatted url string and just call it with a 'response.redirect()' in the codebehind.

```
public string submit()
    {
        //using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        //{
        //    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "appplication/x-www-form     urlencoded";
            NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
            nvc.Add("cmd", "_xclick");
            nvc.Add("business", business);
            nvc.Add("item_name", item_name); //cartname
            nvc.Add("currency_code", currency_code);
            nvc.Add("amount", amount.ToString());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string s in nvc.AllKeys)
            {
                sb.Append(s + "=" + nvc[s] + "&");
            }

            return URI + sb.ToString().TrimEnd('&');
       // }
    }
```

Then just call the submit method from your button click event in the 'Response.Redirect()'

```
 PAYPAL pp = new PAYPAL();
         protected void img_paywithpaypal_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(pp.submit(), false);

    }
```

Hope this helps others...

Comment: Hi jagallout, could you please remove the solution from your question and add the parts you deem usefull to your answer of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Answer edited in original question.  The solution to the paypal asp.net form issue is as follows:

1. programmatically generate the form elements and values.  (I used a NameValueCollection)
2. Build your url string.  Eg:

   "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + "cmd=_xclick" + "&" + "business=" + yourAccountVariable + "&" + "item_name" (or cart name for aggregate totals) + yourCartTotalVariable + ETC ETC ETC ETC ETC for each of paypals required or optional     parameters based on your requirements
3. pass your concatenated string into a 'Response.Redirect()' in your button click event where you want to send your users to the paypal site to pay:

   PAYPAL pp = new PAYPAL();
        protected void img_paywithpaypal_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
   {
       Response.Redirect(pp.submit(), false);

   }

Hope this helps anyone else...